# edge deletion from planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Could anyone help me how to solve this?

We noted that every non-planar graph contains an edge so that if we erase this edge then the crossing number of the new graph is smaller.

• Is there a graph such that no matter which edge is deleted the crossing number of the new graph is smaller?

• Is there a graph such that no matter which edge is deleted the crossing number of the new graph reduces by two or more?

Comment: @Crostul the complete graph with $4$ vertices is planar...  Draw a triangle, draw a vertex in the middle of the triangle.  Include the remaining edges.

Comment: What about the complete graph with 5 vertices